# How to get email alert if one of raid 1 disks fails?

Tags: raid, software-raid

I need to know how can I get email alert if one of raid 1 disks fail to work/crashes. I have CentOS 6.4 64bits, software raid.

I did some mistake folowing [this tutorial](http://novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7001034), because it was a bottom note

> NOTE: It has been found that mdadm will not send an e-mail if the
>   DEVICE partitions section does not exist in the /etc/mdadm.conf file.
>   If those sections do not exist a new /etc/mdadm.conf file can be
>   created by using the following command: mdadm –detail –scan >
>   /etc/mdadm.conf"

I executed that line and my mdadm.conf file was empty whith that response from ssh : `"mdadm: An option must be given to set the mode before a second device (–scan) is listed"`

I also undestand I have to start it using this ssh line: `mdadm –monitor –scan –daemonize` 
but I get this response `"
mdadm: An option must be given to set the mode before a second device
       (–scan) is listed
"`

this is 'cat /proc/mdstat' :

```
  Personalities : [raid1]
  md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda2[0]
  117153664 blocks super 1.1 [2/2] [UU]
  bitmap: 1/1 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

   unused devices: <none>
```

and

```
 mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
    Version : 1.1
  Creation Time : Sat Aug 17 09:19:15 2013
 Raid Level : raid1
  Array Size : 117153664 (111.73 GiB 119.97 GB)
 Used Dev Size : 117153664 (111.73 GiB 119.97 GB)
  Raid Devices : 2
 Total Devices : 2
 Persistence : Superblock is persistent

 Intent Bitmap : Internal

  Update Time : Mon Sep 16 18:55:19 2013
      State : active
  Active Devices : 2
 Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
 Spare Devices : 0

       Name : trader:0
       UUID : 0944131a:0513ca86:cb8ad6c5:3baca49f
     Events : 1751

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8        2        0      active sync   /dev/sda2
   1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

mdadm.conf file generated 1 minute ago with mdadm --examine --scan > /etc/mdadm.conf :

```
  MAILADDR mymail@gmail.com
  ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.1 UUID=0944131a:0513ca86:cb8ad6c5:3baca49f name=trader:0
```

Is this enough to get email notifications if one hdd fails for my case ?

Comment: `man mdadm.conf`, look for `MAILADDR`.

Comment: Thanks but I did some mistake folowing this tutoria http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7001034, because it was a bottom note 'NOTE: It has been found that mdadm will not send an e-mail if the DEVICE partitions section does not exist in the /etc/mdadm.conf file. If those sections do not exist a new /etc/mdadm.conf file can be created by using the following command:
mdadm –detail –scan > /etc/mdadm.conf" I executed that line and my mdadm.conf file is empty now :( whith that response from ssh : mdadm: An option must be given to set the mode before a second device
       (–scan) is listed

Comment: Now I need to restore my file I dont know how.

Comment: Blazer, it sounds like you *have* done some research and work already (good for you!), and that you have a more specific question than the one you've asked.  Your question at the moment is attracting justified downvotes.  I recommend you edit it, and say what you've tried to do, why, what's happened, what you expected, and what the problem is; that will be a respectable question, and hopefully you'll get good answers to it.  In short: **do the work to write a good question in the first place; don't make us tease the story out of you one diagnostic at a time**.

Comment: Better (I've turned my downvote into an upvote!).  Can you also edit into your question the output from `cat /proc/mdstat`?

Comment: I just did it MadHatter.

Comment: Blazer - You need to look into doing version control of your file system, or some sort of backups.  My preference is to version /etc, /usr/local, and /opt using FSVS (fsvs.tigris.org) which stores the data in an SVN repository.  That way I can commit all changes prior to installing software, commit again after the install, commit again after configuration.  Then I can always go back in time to see what I changed and when.

Answer (score 3):

Blazer, it looks like in the process of improving your question (which is now a good one, by the way), you've found your own answer.  Well done, you!  But there is a little more that could usefully be said.

As far as I know, that `mdadm.conf` will suffice for you to get automated notifications.  Certainly, mine looks very little different to that, and I know from a recent failout test that I get notifications.  (I'm a little curious about the second slash in `/dev/md/0`, but if that's what your system wrote, it's very likely right.)

But it's axiomatic in professional sysadmin that, unless you've tested something, you can't really know that it works.

At the very least, you will want to check that you can send mail from that system, as root, to the specified gmail.com address, and receive it.

If I were you, I'd at least perform a soft failure test.  You can do that with `mdadm /dev/md0 -f /dev/sdb1`.  That will fail the second partition out of the array, and should generate a formal notification to you (check your system's mail logs to see if it's gone).  Check the output of `cat /proc/mdstat` so you know what a half-bad array looks like.

You can resync the array later with `mdadm /dev/md0 -a /dev/sdb1`, and check that it's sync'ed back with another `cat /proc/mdstat`.

If you want to go the whole hog, schedule some downtime, try pulling one of the drives, and check that the system can still boot.  Where the metadevice in question is the boot partition, people sometimes forget to have a GRUB boot block on **both** drives, so when the second one fails, their system becomes unbootable.  Replace and resync the drive later.

Whatever tests you decide to do, document them, so that when there's a real failure, you know what to expect, and you can minimise the chance of pilot error trashing the second drive.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not enough. In short, you need to install a nullmailer or some other mailing software, and configure it.

I struggled with this very setup, and finally got it to work. Here is my post about it: [nullmailer - Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 550 5.1.0 <root@external_email_server.com> sender rejected (497)](https://serverfault.com/questions/1006562/nullmailer-diagnostic-code-smtp-550-5-1-0-rootexternal-email-server-com-s)

`nullmailer` should send an alert email to ***alert_recipient@example.com*** using an external mail server at ***smtp.external_email_server.com***.

My smpt account with the external mail provider is ***me@my_domain_hosted_by_provider.com***

## SETUP

### nullmailer

/etc/mailname with the value:

```
external_email_server.com
```

/etc/nullmailer/defaulthost is also set to

```
external_email_server.com
```

/etc/nullmailer/adminaddr

```
me@my_domain_hosted_by_provider.com
```

/etc/nullmailer/allmailfrom

```
me@my_domain_hosted_by_provider.com
```

### mdadm configuration

I followed [these instructions](https://chirale.org/2018/07/30/use-external-mail-server-for-mdadm/).

/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf

```
...
# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system 
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
#   is defined in /etc/aliases so no need to use MAILADDR
MAILADDR alertrecipient@examplesomewhereelse.com
MAILFROM me@my_domain_hosted_by_provider.com
...
```

/etc/aliases

```
root: alertrecipient@examplesomewhereelse.com
postmaster: alertrecipient@examplesomewhereelse.com
default: alertrecipient@examplesomewhereelse.com
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/439921)

Comment: @DaveM good point, I added the essential parts to the answer.