# nullmailer - Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 550 5.1.0 <root@external_email_server.com> sender rejected (497)

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, mdadm

What did I miss-configure to be getting MAILER-DAEMON errors?

*(I was trying to keep this post short, but it got a bit out of hand.)*

I am setting up an email alert system for when my RAID1 should go down.

I installed [nullmailer](https://wiki.debian.org/nullmailer) as MTA on Ubuntu 19.10, and [followed these instructions to do that](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/nullmailer/).

`nullmailer` should send an alert email to ***alert_recipient@example.com*** using an external mail server at ***smtp.external_email_server.com***.

My smpt account with the external mail provider is ***me@my_domain_hosted_by_provider.com***

It looks like `nullmailer`  is able to relay the email to the external email provider, but the delivery from there is getting **sender rejected** error:

> Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 550 5.1.0 root@external_email_server.com sender rejected (497)

---

I've noticed that there is no problem sending and receiving emails if I edit the `nullmailer` generated file in the queue from:

```
me@localhost
alert_recipient@example.com

...
```

to

```
me@my_domain_hosted_by_provider.com
alert_recipient@example.com

...
```

It looks like maybe this [nullmailer Rewrite Wrapper](https://github.com/JsBergbau/nullmailer-Rewrite-Wrapper) could do this, but I am hoping for something more intuitive.

The `/etc/nullmailer/allmailfrom` answer to this, found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505750/why-is-nullmailer-appending-my-hostname-to-the-recipient-address) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124620/what-simpler-mail-server-can-i-use-instead-of-postfix) is a way to override this issue, but what if one has more then one SMTP provider?

---

To test `nullmailer` email delivery I use

```
echo "error" | NULLMAILER_NAME="Testsytem check" mail
     -s "This is just a test with nullmailer" "alert_recipient@example.com"
```

The above test generates this reject alert email from "Message Delivery Subsystem" MAILER-DAEMON@external_email_server.com:

```
The message attached below could not be delivered to one or 
more of the intended recipients:

<alert_recipient@example.com>

Reporting-MTA: x-local-hostname; external_email_server.com
Arrival-Date: Wed, 11 Mar 2020 10:49:26 -0700

Final-Recipient: rfc822; alert_recipient@example.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.0
Last-Attempt-Date: Wed, 11 Mar 2020 10:49:26 -0700
Remote-MTA: dns; smtp.external_email_server.com

Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 550 5.1.0 <root@external_email_server.com> sender rejected (497)
```

I believe that maybe somehow the sender "root@external_email_server.com" should be instead "me@my_domain_hosted_by_provider.com" (not sure.)

---

And, (somewhat unrelated, but not sure) I am also getting this *Failed to start Nullmailer** in the `/var/log/syslog` entries, when restarting `nullmailer` with `sudo service nullmailer restart`:

```
Mar 11 10:49:29 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped Nullmailer relay-only MTA.
Mar 11 10:49:29 localhost systemd[1]: nullmailer.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 11 10:49:29 localhost systemd[1]: nullmailer.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Mar 11 10:49:29 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start Nullmailer relay-only MTA.
```

---

When testing mdadm mailing alerts I am using this, which somehow stragely puts a total of out 3 emails in the queue. And, what is strange is that it looks like the queue only gets processed when `nullmailer` gets restarted:

```
sudo mdadm --monitor --scan --test -1
```

---

## SETUP

### nullmailer

At first I was using `/etc/nullmailer/me` with

```
external_email_server.com
```

but this gave me a warning in the error log `/var/log/mail.log`

> Warning: On Debian systems, nullmailer's 'me' is disregarded; please use '/etc/mailname' instead.

So I deleted the file `/etc/nullmailer/me` and instead am using `/etc/mailname` with the value:

```
external_email_server.com
```

/etc/nullmailer/defaulthost is also set to

```
external_email_server.com
```

/etc/nullmailer/adminaddr

```
me@my_domain_hosted_by_provider.com
```

### mdadm configuration

I followed [these instructions](https://chirale.org/2018/07/30/use-external-mail-server-for-mdadm/).

/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf

```
...
# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system 
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
#   is defined in /etc/aliases so no need to use MAILADDR
MAILADDR alertrecipient@examplesomewhereelse.com
MAILFROM me@my_domain_hosted_by_provider.com
...
```

/etc/aliases

```
root: alertrecipient@examplesomewhereelse.com
postmaster: alertrecipient@examplesomewhereelse.com
default: alertrecipient@examplesomewhereelse.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding setupfile `/etc/nullmailer/allmailfrom` worked.

Put the email address you want the mail to be sent **From** in there.

/etc/nullmailer/allmailfrom

```
me@my_domain_hosted_by_provider.com
```